# How to read Contacts from Android 1.5 emulator?

Tags: android

I created one application to read all the contacts stored in android 2.0 emulator.I want to do the same thing for android 1.5 emulator, but the same code is not working for android 1.5.I don't know how to do it.If any body knows please help me.

Comment: Check the many duplicate questions on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the example on following site : http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/2/